# Record Table Changes - MS Access

Tags: logging, audit, change-tracking

I am currently a manger of an Access Database. I am looking to get some help to try to track the edits made to some of the TABLES, not the Forms.

In the database, there is already an audit log keeping track of some of the changes made to a table (in a form-datasheet view), without any problems.

There are a few other forms in the database where users can upload excel spreadsheets into the database, and the import will put that data from the excel spreadhseet into its respective table in the database and overwrite the previous data.  I also have update functions where it can just update the records of data as opposed to simply overwriting the data.

I am looking to be able to be able to do either (or both) of the following:

- Track the differences between the data that is ALREADY in the database compared to the data that is being UPLOADED into the database
- Record a change of a record in certain tables (and be able to see old/new values like how I currently have it done in the form view)

I have been searching around, and only found ways to track changes made in the Form-Spreadsheet view like I currently am doing. I am now looking to see if there are other ways I can accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Data Marcos

Beginning with MS Access 2010, you can use what is known as Data Macros. Use your favorite web search engine (i.e. Google) and search for MS Access data macros. This will allow you to respond to changes in your tables' data.

This functionality is known as Triggers in major Relational Database Management Systems (RDMS).